# python default dict argument is getting cached across function calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm coming from a js world and not able to wrap this minor quirk in my head.
Consider this simple python program:

**lib.py**

```
def test(i, memo=dict()):
  memo[i] = i
  print(memo)
  return i
```

I'm calling this from repl:

```
>>> import lib
>>> lib.test(1)
{1: 1}
1

>>> lib.test(2)
{1: 1, 2: 2}
2

>>> lib.test(3)
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
3
```

maybe I'm missing something about python module imports or such - I expected the memo to be initialized with new dictionary each time I call it but it has the knowledge of previous invocations.

Comment: Functions are also objects and are initialized just once, when they are defined. The `memo=dict()` acts like an instance member for that function and retains its state across call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like:

```
def test(i, memo=None):
  memo = {} if memo is None else memo
  memo[i] = i
  print(memo)
  return i
```

https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments for more info.

Comment: Except this looks like a legitimate use case for the mutable default argument. i.e., memoization.

Comment: thanks for the link - something new in python I learnt today